# Asking the same old ques again : The requested resource is not available

Tags: rest, jersey

I am using jersey. This is how my project looks.

[image]

web.xml looks like :[image]

I have added all the dependencies in pom. Still getting the "resource not available" error while hiiting "http://localhost:5656/UserManagementRest/" . Please suggest what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

// I guess you need to spacify ur base package name where you are writing your service classes are exists

```
  <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>packagename</param-value>   // com.example.service
  </init-param>
```